# Getting OCI-22303: type "AQ_MANAGER"."MCKB_CMD_T" not found

Tags: oracle

When I am running the below query from my user account then getting the subject error.

```
Select * from CMD.CMD_AUDIT;
```

When I ran the same query from super user then able to run successfully.
I checked old articles regarding same, they said this is the version issue with toad. But in my case using same toad version, only the issue is with differ user account.

Could you please help me in this?

Comment: is there any column with object type?. Please add table description.

Comment: are you getting this during a data pump? I feel like we're missing some of your issue here.